# JSON Windows exe through Wine

Tags: wine, json

I am from India. The Income Tax efiling site was providing .jar file which could be run through JRE Version 8 to prepare the Income Tax Return since the year 2013-14 till 2020-21 (for 8 years) and I could use it on Ubuntu.

For the year 2021-22 they are shifting to JSON but providing only Windows exe file.

I tried to run it through Wine on Ubuntu 20.04 but it does not work.

I would be grateful if some expert can make it work on Wine, otherwise I have to go back to Windows to file the Income Tax Return.

One can download the Windows exe file from here
https://www.incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/downloads/incomeTaxReturnUtilities?lang=eng

When I run the exe file I get this error and blank screen:

```
$ wine ITDe-Filing.exe

004f:err:seh:raise_exception Unhandled exception code c0000005 flags 0 addr 0x7bccf0bf
http://125.16.30.183:2033/updates/win/
08:58:37.518 > Checking for update
08:58:37.600 > [code-updater ] AppPath: C:\users\vidya\Local Settings\Application Data\Programs\ITDe-Filing\resources\app.asar/
08:58:37.602 > [code-updater ] AppPathFolder: C:\users\vidya\Local Settings\Application Data\Programs\ITDe-Filing\resources\
08:58:37.604 > [code-updater ] 0.1.1
null
null
08:58:37.999 > [code-updater ] Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1056:14)
08:58:38.002 > [code-updater ] Could not connect
```

On Apr 14 I installed wine-6.6 (Staging) by adding wine-hq repo and it works.
Kamalakar

Comment: Did you check and see if Wine even supports that program?

Comment: This application is Electron based. It would be easier to install it on Windows VM and then remove the VM after usage.

Comment: @N0rbert Does it mean it could be ported to Linux since Electron is cross platform?

Comment: linux filing option will also be provided, wait

Comment: I installed wine-6.6 (Staging) by adding wine-hq repo and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I installed wine-6.6 (Staging) by adding wine-hq repo and it works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1137307)

Comment: @TejasLotlikar Thank god. You are from India. Are you willing to test the exe file on wine-6.6? Although I have answered my own question the problem is not fully solved. I could fill up the Income Tax Return completely, verify it but at last stage when the output JSON file is supposed to be downloaded it does not work. It says "Download Failed".

Comment: NB: It is working on Windows including the download of output JSON file.